# Python Speech recognition 1.1.4 doesn't receive input from microphone

Tags: speech-recognition, windows-7-x64, python-3.4

When I try to use the Speech Recognition module for python with provided example code to use with microphone.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))
except LookupError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Program starts running and it constantly waits for input. I've checked if required PyAudio module works correctly and it is, checked with provided example codes on main site. Input from mic can be clearly heard. The only way I've managed to give it input (sort of) from microphone is by enabling stereo mix and redirecting input to speakers. This was the only case when it worked. I've also tried manually set device index as it was said in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition in Reference section. It didn't work. How can I get it to work without this preparations?
I'm working on Windows 7, using Python 3.4.3, Speech Recognition 1.1.4, PyAudio 0.2.8 provided from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio. All 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify the ID of the microphone.

Inspired from [Getting list of audio Input devices in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838279/getting-list-of-audio-input-devices-in-python), list your devices like this :

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print(info['index'], info['name'])
```

For example, in my case the result is :

```
0 HDA Intel MID: ALC888 Analog (hw:0,0)
1 HDA Intel MID: ALC888 Alt Analog (hw:0,2)
2 HDA Intel MID: ALC888 Digital (hw:0,3)
...
7 Logitech G35 Headset: USB Audio (hw:2,0)
...
17 pulse
18 dmix
19 default
```

My mic is on my headset, its device id is 7. Then i use this line :

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=7) as source:
```