# Getting list of audio input devices in Python

Tags: python-2.7, audio, device

How do I get the list of audio input devices in Linux using Python in this format as `hw:0,1`?

I've tried the following using pyaudio:

```
def getaudiodevices():
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        print p.get_default_input_device_info()
        for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
                print ''#p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
```

I'm also able to retrieve using "`arecord -l`" but I need to just get it like:

hw:0,1
hw:0,2

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name stored by the PaDeviceInfo structure is sufficient, then you could just access the 'name' from the dict returned by `get_device_info_by_index()`, and then perhaps slice the information off the end:

```
import pyaudio

def getaudiodevices():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
        print p.get_device_info_by_index(i).get('name')
```

gives me

```
HDA Intel HDMI: 0 (hw:0,3)
HDA Intel HDMI: 1 (hw:0,7)
HDA Intel HDMI: 2 (hw:0,8)
HDA Intel PCH: CS4208 Analog (hw:1,0)
HDA Intel PCH: CS4208 Digital (hw:1,1)
hdmi
default
```

But this doesn't give you what you want with the default devices, the name seems to be stored as "default". In that case, executing "`arecord -l`" in Python can work, if that's what you're looking for. Of course, you can do the same thing for "`aplay -l`".

```
import os

def getaudiodevices():
    devices = os.popen("arecord -l")
    device_string = devices.read()
    device_string = device_string.split("\n")
    for line in device_string:
            if(line.find("card") != -1):
                print "hw:" + line[line.find("card")+5] + "," +\
 line[line.find("device")+7]
```

outputs

```
hw:1,0
```